# Display Sum value in SSRS 2005 Reports?

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I am trying to display sum of one of the table in my report using SSRS 2005.

So basically it should be just one row with sum of all values in each column, I used sum expression but the result data gets repeated with same values.

Can anybody please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your table there should be three rows.  The header, detail, and footer.  It sounds like you may have put your data in the detail, try moving it to the footer row and see what happens.  If that isn't it, we'll need more detail about how you have organized the table.